# BKF Conversion to vmware compatable filetype

Tags: conversion, backup

trying to restore (DR test) exch and dc in one box to vmware environment
unable to use vmware converter, only have NT backup files of server (said box has exch & dc on it windows 2k3 environemnt) any ideas or tools to use etc ?

Answer (score 1):

BKF isn't a disk image format, but is more like a "ZIP" or other "archive" file (TAR, CPIO, etc). Your best bet is going to be to use NTBackup to restore the backups.

If you still have the original hardware the backups were taken on I'd recommend restoring the backup on the original hardware then performing the physical-to-virtual conversion.

If you don't have the original hardware you might try performing a disaster recovery restore inside a VM you build up for that purpose. With the changes in hardware between the backup and the VM (and no P2V software to "massage" those changes away) you're likely going to have problems.